# I can open but not prepare an SQL statement

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

The return code from `sqlite3_prepare_v2` was 1 - error. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    NSLog(@"Error. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```